# programmatically identify methods that override trait methods

Tags: php

I'm trying to generate an array of methods in a class that override trait methods.  Here is a simplified example that shows the structure of methods of a typical class and trait in my app:

```
class demo
{
    public function MethodA()
    {
        return 'method A from class';
    }

    public function MethodC()
    {
        return 'method C from class';
    }

    public function MethodE()
    {
        return 'method E from class';
    }

    use tGeneric;
}

trait tGeneric
{
    public function MethodA()
    {
        return 'method A from trait';
    }

    public function MethodB()
    {
        return 'method B from trait';
    }

    public function MethodD()
    {
        return 'method D from trait';
    }

    public function MethodE()
    {
        return 'method E from trait';
    }
}
```

Per the precedence rules listed in the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php):

> The precedence order is that methods from the current class override Trait methods, which in turn override methods from the base class.

this is behaving as expected because the output from this code:

```
$object = new demo();
$array = [
    $object->MethodA(),
    $object->MethodB(),
    $object->MethodC(),
    $object->MethodD(),
    $object->MethodE()
];

$br = '<br>';
$msg = '';

foreach ($array as $value):
    $msg .= $value . $br;
endforeach;
echo $msg . $br;
```

is:
[image]

The methods in the class `demo` that override the trait methods from `tGeneric` are MethodA() and MethodE().  Is there a way to programmatically generate an array of just these methods in the class that override the methods from the trait?

I have experimented with reflection but the `GetMethods()` method retrieves all methods for a class, regardless of whether they originated in the class or were obtained via the use of a trait.

This code:

```
$rc = new ReflectionClass('demo');
$d = $rc->GetMethods();

$traits = class_uses('demo');
foreach ($traits as $trait):
    $reflection = new ReflectionClass($trait);
    $t = $reflection->GetMethods();
endforeach;

DisplayInfo($d);
DisplayInfo($t);

function DisplayInfo($array)
{
    $br = '<br>';
    echo '<b>' . $array[0]->class . '</b>' .  $br;
    foreach ($array as $value):
        echo $value->name . $br;
    endforeach; 
    echo $br;
}
```

gives this output:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make *almost* sure a method overrides a trait method by comparing:

- their file names
  ([`ReflectionFunctionAbstract::getFileName`](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionfunctionabstract.getfilename.php)),
- and their start lines ([`ReflectionFunctionAbstract::getStartLine`](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionfunctionabstract.getstartline.php))

### Condition

```
if ($class_method->getFileName() !== $trait_method->getFileName() 
    || $class_method->getStartLine() !== $trait_method->getStartLine()) {
  $methods_overridden[] = $class_method->getName();
}
```

(of course, they also need to have the same name)

### Full function

```
/**
 * Given a class name, retrieves the corresponding class' methods that override
 * trait methods.
 *
 * @param string $class_name
 * @return \ReflectionMethod[]
 * @throws \ReflectionException
 */
function getMethodsOverriddenFromTraits(string $class_name): array
{
  $class = new \ReflectionClass($class_name);

  // Retrieve trait methods

  $trait_methods = [];
  foreach ($class->getTraits() as $trait) {
    foreach ($trait->getMethods() as $trait_method) {
      $trait_methods[$trait_method->getName()] = $trait_method;
    }
  }

  // Compute class methods that override them

  $methods_overridden = [];
  foreach ($class->getMethods() as $class_method) {
    if (array_key_exists($class_method->getName(), $trait_methods)) {
      $trait_method = $trait_methods[$class_method->getName()];
      if ($class_method->getFileName() !== $trait_method->getFileName() 
          || $class_method->getStartLine() !== $trait_method->getStartLine()) {
        $methods_overridden[] = $class_method->getName();
      }
    }
  }

  return $methods_overridden;
}
```

**Demo here: https://3v4l.org/EcFIC**

Comment: In my app the classes and traits are in separate files, unlike the simplified example I provided in the original post.  So is there any reason to include the `getStartLine` method in the condition that determines class methods that override trait methods in the code for the app?  Just want to make sure I'm not overlooking something.  My assumption is that `getStartLine` was included in your solution for this post so the original example would work correctly in the demo you provided...is that correct?

Comment: @knot22 That's exactly right. The idea is to have it work in as many different cases as possible, but you can omit the start line condition if your traits are always in distinct files.

Comment: OK, excellent.  Another thing in your solution I'm wondering about, that I haven't seen before, is the `function getMethodsOverriddenFromTraits(string $class_name): array` - specifically the `: array` part.  Googling did not help me find an answer for the purpose of `: array`.  What does that do?

Comment: It's the PHP7 way of stating what the function will return (unfortunately, you can't be more specific than `array`). You can omit it without any issues if you're not running PHP7 or if your other functions/methods don't use that syntax. See [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php#functions.returning-values.type-declaration) for more info.

Comment: Ah ha - good to know.  I'm using an older version of PHP for the time being (5.4.4).  Also, in this line `$class = new \ReflectionClass($class_name);` what is the purpose of including the backslash in front of `ReflectionClass`?

Comment: A leading backslash before a class name means you're looking for a class of that name that exists within the default (root) namespace, such as `ReflectionClass` and any other class that is defined by PHP's standard library. If you omit it, PHP will look for the class in the current namespace. So for instance if you add `namespace My\Great\App;` on top of your code, then referencing `ReflectionClass` without it will fail because it will look for `My\Great\App\ReflectionClass`. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Very thorough answers, Jeto.  Much obliged for all of your help.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution would be more applicable if it was more a real code scenario where your traits and classes where in individual files - which should be how you code anyway (IMHO)...

So I put the trait code in a file (I've called it TraitTest.php).  Then in my main script is the rest of the code you have, but of course using `require_once 'TraitTest.php';`.  Then in the `DisplayInfo()` function, I've just added the value of `getFileName()`, which shows the filename where the method is defined...

```
function DisplayInfo($array)
{
    $br = PHP_EOL;
    echo '<b>' . $array[0]->class . '</b>' .  $br;
    foreach ($array as $value)  {
        echo $value->getFileName()."->".$value->name . $br;
    }
    echo $br;
}
```

which shows...

```
<b>demo</b>
/home/nigel/workspace2/Test/t1.php->MethodA
/home/nigel/workspace2/Test/t1.php->MethodC
/home/nigel/workspace2/Test/t1.php->MethodE
/home/nigel/workspace2/Test/TraitTest.php->MethodB
/home/nigel/workspace2/Test/TraitTest.php->MethodD

<b>TraitTest</b>
/home/nigel/workspace2/Test/TraitTest.php->MethodA
/home/nigel/workspace2/Test/TraitTest.php->MethodB
/home/nigel/workspace2/Test/TraitTest.php->MethodD
/home/nigel/workspace2/Test/TraitTest.php->MethodE
```

As you can see, `MethodB` is showing up as being defined in `TraitTest.php`.